# Как сайту разрешить доступ к микрофону в хроме?

Tags: google-chrome, безопасность

У сайта нет сертификата. Для демонстрации работы, приложение залито на хостинг и прикреплено к временному домену. В настройках хрома не могу разрешить доступ к микрофону. "Заблокировано в целях безопасности" и селект рядом дисэйбл. Что-то можно с этим сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.sslforfree.com/ бесплатный сертификат на 3 месяца